# get integer from textfile and write to excel with python

Tags: python, excel

I already get the value from text file and write it to excel file. But somehow in the excel cell the integer written in string. So there's a green triangle in the cell. Like this
[image: This is the output of the file]

I want to print like this

[image]

and this is the code

```
from itertools import chain
import glob ,csv, sys, os

sys.path.insert(0,'D:/apera/Python27/xlwt-0.7.5')

import xlwt

openMesureFile = 'D:/apera/Workspace/Python scripting test 2/sounding0.txt'
savePlace = 'D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding{0:03d}.txt'
openSoundingFile = 'D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/*.txt'

with open(openMesureFile, 'rb') as inf:
    header = next(inf)
    for index, line in enumerate(inf,start=0):
        with open(savePlace.format(index) ,'w') as outf:
            outf.write('Filename:;%s\n\n' %outf.name)

            outf.write(header)
            for line in chain([line], inf):
                if 'Sounding :;Sondage n°' in line:
                    header = line
                    break
                outf.write(line)

for filename in glob.glob(openSoundingFile):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="latin1")
    sheet = wb.add_sheet('INPUT')
    newName = filename
    spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=';',quotechar='"')
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)

    sheet.col(0).width = 5555
    sheet.col(1).width = 11110
    sheet.col(2).width = 5555
    sheet.col(3).width = 3333

    wb.save(newName[:-4] + ".xls")

print "success"
```

Comment: You can type cast `value` in the statement. That is `sheet.write(rowx, colx, float(value))`. That has always worked for me. Do try and check.

Comment: `csv` won't implicitly cast the numbers to `float`; you have to do it manually - `sheet.write(rowx, colx, float(value))`.

Comment: `write()` in python always takes an argument of type `str`. Therefore, it will always write string in the file.

Comment: @AmitSharma this isn't `file.write`, it's [`xlwt.Worksheet.write`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966#xlwt.Worksheet.write-method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966)

> write(r, c, label="", style=Style.default_style) [#]
>       label
>           The data value to be written. An int, long, or decimal.Decimal instance is converted to float.

Thus a `str` input will be taken as a `string` in excel. Thus you will have to type cast it explicitly.

In your program this can be done from changing a single line:

from

```
 sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)
```

to

```
 sheet.write(rowx, colx, float(value))
```

Comment: sheet.write(rowx, colx, float(value))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Filename:                its still not working. Is there other way?

Comment: yeah there have other strings in it.. So I'll try to split it first. Thanks

Comment: i try it with no string file but it still error                    TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number